# Order MySQL table by rotating values

Tags: mysql, repeat

I have table with phone numbers. I want to sort that table by the begining of each number, but it has to be repeated. For example, there are rows like:

```
phone_number
0911226778
0905625238
0907952386
0904235582
```

First four digits determine provider. Prefixes with 0911 and 0904 belong to provider A and 0905 and 0907 to provider B. I would like to sort table accoridng to phone number based on provider. What I want is to order table like A, B, A, B, etc., where "A" represents a bunch of prefixes as well as "B". So desired order would look like:

```
phone_number
0911226778
0905625238
0904235582
0907952386
```

I found examples using UNION statement or something similar. The problem is I want to change very complicated query inside php script. Since I am not skilled, I want to find simple method how to do it just using ORDER BY statement or with little changes to WHERE clause.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via an `ORDER BY CASE` where you take the first 4 characters of the `phone_number` via `LEFT(phone_number, 4)`:

```
SELECT
  phone_number
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY
  CASE
    /* first group of A prefixes */
    WHEN LEFT(phone_number, 4) IN ('0911','other_a','another_a') THEN 1
    /* first group of B prefixes */
    WHEN LEFT(phone_number, 4) IN ('0905','other_b','another_b') THEN 2
    /* second group of A prefixes */
    WHEN LEFT(phone_number, 4) IN ('0904','some_a','someother_a') THEN 3
    /* second group of B prefixes */
    WHEN LEFT(phone_number, 4) IN ('0907','some_b','someother_b') THEN 4
    ELSE 5
  END ASC,
  phone_number ASC
```

Substitute other prefixes inside the `IN()`  where I have `other_a`, etc.... What this does is match the first 4 chars, and if they are in the assigned sorting group, simply apply a number to order by.  In the example above, all the 0911, other_a, another_a would be given a 1, thus sorting ahead of the 0905, other_b, another_b, and the next group of A you happen to assign.

Inside those groups, a regular ascending sort is applied to `phone_number`.

I think I understand from your question that you have more prefixes for A and B than the 4 you listed. If that isn't correct, you can replace the `IN()` clauses below with a simple `= '0904'` for example.

This method may unfortunately not be very friendly to indexing.  If performance doesn't meet your needs, I would suggest storing the prefix as a `CHAR(4)` in a separate column (with an index) and using that in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: It's almost what I need. I was wondering, if it's possible to print just one row from every gorup (let's say I only set two groups) and then repeat? For instance just one row from the first group then one row from the second group, etc. Your answer helped me anyway because now I know the base idea.

Comment: @user1609926 Getting one row at a time alternating from the groups is going to be a lot harder in plain SQL.  I can think of some ways using temporary tables, unions, and incrementing row numbers, but it is really complicated.  In that case, I would probably handle it in your application code. Run two queries, one for A and one for B, then loop over the results grabbing one row from each in alternation.